# Firebase storage slow when delivering public images

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to upload avatars (original.jpg).
In a node.js background process I resize them with gm and then put them back in my firebase bucket. These pictures are publicly readable, see my storage rules :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/xxx.appspot.com/o {
    match /images {
      match /{allImages=**} {
        allow read;
      }
      match /{userId}/avatar/original.jpg {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I store the url of images in firebase database ex:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/images%2Fyyy%2Favatar%2Fzzz-small.jpg?alt=media
```

That I retrieved right after the file upload (web sdk) `var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;` ; stripped off the token parameter as it's gonna be public ; and where zzz-small.jpg has replaced original.jpg.

It works, pictures are displayed.

But it's slow even though the picture is a 40x40px jpg. And it hangs for a while before actually downloading the file, see Chrome Network record :

[Chrome network record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTeJP.png)

The file is 158B, there's a ~1s waiting before the download ~3ms...

Is firebase storage supposed to be as fast as a CDN ?
Any faster way to call a public readable file ?

[EDIT]
Got some feedback from Firebase support :

> We're definitely aware that many users, such as yourself, are having
>   issues with slow downloading of file from Europe. We're exploring
>   potential solutions, but I can't share any details or timelines at
>   this time. We'll keep your feedback in consideration moving forward
>   though.
>
> Keep an eye out on our release notes for any further updates.

I forgot to mention I'm in Europe and the storage in the US.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?