# Right way to show images stored in firebase.storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When my user uploads and image, the app saves it in firebase storage and gets the download-url and saves it in the database. I use the url in the database to show the image but it gets really really slow (< 2 seconds) to show the image. On the other hand, firebase database is blazing fast.

Is this the correct way to show images or am I doing something that is non performant?

Edit: I have seen other posts that also have slowness issues but none of them seem to have a solution ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144743/firebase-storage-slow-when-delivering-public-images?rq=1)). I live in Europe and storage is in the US. The images are under 400kb, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Code:

```
// creating reference
const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/jobs/${currentUser.uid}/${jobUID}`).child(name)

// creating a Blob using fileReader
fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
.then((data) => {
  console.log('data from readFile: ', data)
  return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
})
.then((blob) => {
  uploadBlob = blob;

  return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime, name: name })
    .then(url => {

    // URL used to display image
    let imgUrl = url.downloadURL

    // upload url to database
    let storageRef = firebase.database().ref(`/jobs/activeJobs/${currentUser.uid}/${jobUID}/`);
          storageRef.update(photo1).then(() => console.log('success'))
```

To retrieve the image I just place the downloadURL in an Image tag

Comment: It would help us to answer the question if we knew what platform you were using and also take a look at your code to see how you are storing/retrieving these images. Include your code snippet as TEXT please no images. Also, you may want to ping your firebase to see how long it's taking. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Well As I mentioned I am using the JS API. I am storing my images how its documented in firebase. Creating a ref and then using the .put() method: `const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/jobs/${currentUser.uid}/${jobUID}').child(name)`
`imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime, name: name })`. As I mentioned, connection to the database is fine, its just storage.

Comment: Please include code in your question, not in the comments as it's really difficult to read.

Comment: @Jay I  updated! I still think it is not my code that is the problem but its a firebase / firebase-settings issue. That is the reason why I omitted the code.